# Can't Connect to EC2 Via SSH or HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

So I was trying to connect to my server after via HTTP but it didn't work, I tried
VPCs, Elastic IPs(VPC), Firewalls, Route Tables, Security Groups, Internet Gateways, Subnets, And Network ACLs
I restarted my EC2 Instance and now SSH is not working, I'm getting Connection Timed Out on SSH and Connection Refused on HTTP

[ Network ACLs Inbound: (Rule number: 100, Type: HTTP (80), Protocol: TCP (6), Port range: 80, Source: 0.0.0.0/0) Outbound: (Rule number: 100, Type: All Traffic, Protocol: All, Port range: All, Source: 0.0.0.0/0) ]

[ Subnets: us-east-1,a us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1e, us-east-1f ]

[ Internet Gateways: ID: igw-55a2722f ]

[ Security Groups: Port Range: 22 - 80, CIDR Block: 0.0.0.0/0 ]

[ Route Tables: Routes: local and igw-55a2722f, igw-55a2722f's Destination is 0.0.0.0/0, local's destination is 172.31.0.0/16 ]

[ Firewalls: Priority: 1,  Protocol: TCP,  Source: 172.31.0.0/16, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0, Source Port Range: 22:80, Destination Port Range: 22:80 ]

[ Elastic IP: 107.23.177.116 ]

[ VPCs: IPv4 CIDR:  172.31.0.0/16 ]

Comment: Its not clear what is your setup. You need to provide **exact** setup for your  VPCs, Elastic IPs(VPC), Firewalls, Route Tables, Security Groups, Internet Gateways, Subnets, And Network ACLs.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, it's not clear what your setup is, so the problem could be due to many different things. I would probably start by checking if the security group associated with your EC2 instance allows inbound SSH and HTTP(S) traffic.

Comment: Ok I will edit my post to show that data

Comment: Done giving Details @Marcin

Comment: Can you please properly format it, so its easier to read?

Comment: Ok I will do it

Comment: Fixed it mate :) @Marcin

Comment: So now what is it that you try to access using HTTP? A website? What ports does it use? How do you know that it actually works on the instance?

Comment: I don't know so that's why I'm trying to test it via AWS Codedeploy (it's a webapp based on react and node.js) and it was successful in deploying and testing my webapp @Marcin

Comment: Port 80 because that's the HTTP Default

Comment: Hello @Marcin ? Are you offline